# Launching code from CMD works, but not through a PHP exec script... why is this?

Tags: php, windows, cmd

When I login to Windows Server 2008 and run this code using cmd.exe (as an Admin), it works:

```
php -f e:\path\to\file\file-name.php go 4001
```

However, when I try to launch this from a php file, it does not:

```
$cmd = escapeshellarg("php -f e:\path\to\file\file-name.php go 4001");
exec($cmd);
exit;
```

I've been at it for 6 hours and can't find a solution.  I've even tried pstools to enable access to `psexec`, still no luck.  I can't even get psexec to work from the command line because it seems that I'm unable to pass variables through (go and 4001).

**Update**

When I run the code using the PHP file, nothing happens, the file I want to be created does not get created and I'm not sure how to throw errors through this method.

```
<?php
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
}
?>
```

Outputs, exec is enabled.

Please help!

Comment: `It doesn't work` is not a good description of what's happening. Any error messages? Logs? What's the actual and expected output? Is the usage of `exec` allowed in your php.ini?

Comment: you need to double escape for windows , for ex php will consider `\t` in your code as tab , so I suggest you to double escape the \   slashes since your code is enclosed between double quotes `"`

Comment: being in double quotes `"` some of the path to the php file will need escaping also look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: Exec is allowed, and now I've escaped my cmd and it still does not work, again I'm receiving no errors or warnings of any kind. I know it does not work because it's not creating a file I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm receiving no errors or warnings of any kind.

Well, you have this:

```
exec($cmd);
```

And the [function signature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) is this:

> `string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )`

Change your code to make use of the optional arguments that provide error info.

In any case, you're encoding your complete command as a single argument. That cannot work: I count 5 different tokens in your command line, not one. You must encode all 5 items separately and you need to use different functions for *commands* and *arguments*.

Additionally, `escapeshellarg()` is basically a Unix-only function that has been poorly patched so it doesn't have obvious security issues on Windows, but it doesn't work properly on Windows, it'll often strip characters rather than escaping. I found a [nicer replacement at the Symfony framework](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Process/ProcessUtils.php#L37) which is rather easy to adapt for standalone use.